# How to fix tab at top while scrolling inside listview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Need to create layout in flutter like as attached gif.

While scrolling fix `tab` at top of screen & `scroll` content inside `tabbar`.

Tried `SliverAppBar` but can't set Custom Widget UI like showing in Instagram.

[image: Demo_GIF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, and it's simple. You can remember SliverAppBar has pinned property, your solution this.
[image]

**Result:**

[image: My Caption]

If you want detail , look [at this](https://github.com/VB10/stack-over-help-flutter) (lib/instagram-ui).